# Styles not working on iframe contents

Tags: html, wordpress, iframe, paypal

I am trying to style an paypal iframe for a WordPress website. My only problem is that I can't get my styles to actually work. They don't even show up in the styles when inspecting. I can only style the iframe element but none of the contents.

the code goes something like this

```
<iframe>
   #document
   <!doctype html>

   <html>
      <head>
      </head>

      <body>
         //content
      </body>
   </html>
</iframe>
```

What could be stopping me from styling anything inside the iframe? When I look at the styles that are already applied to the contents inside the iframe they are coming from a stylesheet called common.css. From What I have read this stylesheet doesn't exist inside my files instead it is generated on the server side. I could be wrong though. Thanks

Comment: Did you try giving the elements inline style ? What was the result of that ?

Comment: @Jackson Well I did look into the plugins code. But all I can find is the html element. All the rest of the elements seem to be generated from somewhere else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A stylesheet only applies to the page to which it is applied. An iframe is a window to a *completely different* page.

A stylesheet applied to the parent document will not be able to select the elements in the document loaded in the frame.

In order to style elements in the frame, you would need to add the stylesheet to that document. i.e. change the code on Paypal's servers.

Comment: Ok so that makes more sense now. Thanks. So if I add my stylesheet to it somehow my styles should work?

Comment: Yes. If you perform some kind of Mission Impossible style raid on Paypal's data farm, hack into their servers, and edit them to include a link to your stylesheet, then you will be able to style Paypal's pages.

Comment: Hahaha I'll get right on it... Or maybe I'll just look into using a different plugin then. I have no idea why this one isn't responsive. Doesn't seem like paypal would create a non responsive plugin. Maybe the guy before me downloaded a rubbish one. Thanks for the help